# Creating a page on CMS

Tags: content-management-system

For example:

I create a page on Joomla or Wordpress and then save it.

I create an entry in the menu that points to the new page.

When I select the new entry in the menu the page opens on the browser.

The URL that appears points to a file that doesn't exist on the server.

What is the mechanism that is used by a CMS like Joomla or wordpress to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is typically done with a URL rewriting module that runs on the web server (mod_rewrite for Apache or URL Rewrite for IIS on Windows). It will rewrite a request URL like `/blog/article-title` to something like `/index.php/blog/article-title` or `/index.php?q=blog/article-title` before the website code even sees the request. Then, the code in index.php extracts the rest of the path and determines which content to serve based on that.

For Wordpress, see http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks for some info about how the rewrites are set up.